# click on login button on webpage (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to click on login button on one of the website, i can input username and password but i unable to click on button.
below is the elements for login button, please check and help me on this.
thanks.

```html
<a id="ctl00_BodyContent_LoginButton" tabindex="3" class=" sw-btn-primary sw-btn"
  automation="Login" 
  href="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl00$BodyContent$LoginButton&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, true))">
<span class="sw-btn-c"><span class="sw-btn-t">Login</span></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by navigating directly to the href value of the log in button tag.

```
IEobject.Navigate(HtmlDoc.GetElementById(“ctl00_BodyContent_LoginButton“).href)
```

Comment: Please have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) help page about how to format code properly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply now i can navigate till the page i am looking for but i now i want to copy the table data in to the excel but i unable to do that. please advise